# Ошибка "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an  unusual way"

Tags: c++

Можете мне сказать, в чем проблема в этой программе? Я вот ввожу первое слово, значения - все хорошо. А вот после того, как я ввожу второе слово, программа прекращает свою работу с выдачей следующей ошибки:

> "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an  unusual way"

Вот код.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string x, e, y, f;
    int a, b, c, d;

    cout <<"Enter the First world: \n" << endl; 
    getline(cin,x);
    cout <<"\n";

    cout <<"Enter Start and Finish char for the First World: \n" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;

    e = x.substr(a, b);
    cout << e << endl;

    cout <<"Enter the Second world: \n" << endl; 
    getline(cin,y);
    cout <<"\n";

    cout <<"Enter Start and Finish char for the Second World: \n" << endl;
    cin >> c;
    cin >> d;

    f = y.substr(c, d);
    cout << f << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

Из описания метода `string::substr(size_t pos = 0, size_t n = npos)`

> **pos** - position of a character in the
> current string object to be used as
> starting character for the substring.
> If the position passed is past the end
> of the string, an `out_of_range`
> exception is thrown.

Таким образом, если не проверить входные данные для индексов, то можно нарваться на эксепшн `std::out_of_range` *(что и происходит в вашем случае).*

Также отмечу, что это не единственная проблема в вашем коде. Я бы рекомендовал бы вам разобраться, почему строка `y` в вашей программе **оказывается пуста** и исправить это.

Comment: @navi1893 Я, конечно, могу сразу ответить, почему это происходит, но, мне кажется, что будет больше пользы, если вы сами разберетесь. Смотрите в сторону `std::cin.ignore() + std::getline()`

Comment: Котик, это слишком сложно для неокрепших в С++ умов. Не мучайте ребенка.

Comment: @mikillskegg явсего 3-4 месяца с С++. Возможно вы правы.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, не обязательно она **всегда будет пустой**.

Подсказка для @navi1893. Текст для переменной y  можно ввести в *той же строке экрана*, что и число b.

Думайте @navi1893.  Какой символ является **концом вводимой строки ?**

Comment: я вот взял просто переставил местами операции и код сработал. Точнее, я написал getline друг под другом и присвоил их значения e и f в конце и вывел. Так, а в чем была то проблема в первом случае? Прошу чтоб сказали мне

Comment: Ввод числа cin >> b прекращается на первой не цифре и этот символ остается в потоке. Если вводить, как все люди, то это будет '\\n', а getline() считывает символы потока до '\\n', но не включает его в string. 

Поэтому при вводе 

    3 4<ENTER>

переменная y будет пустой.

Comment: а b же у меня типа int, почему тогда она прекращается на первой НЕ цифре???

Comment: А что делать с **не цифрой** при вводе числа ?

@navi1893 почитайте [это](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/) и [это](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/). Обратите внимание на методы good(), clear() и ignore(). 

Потренируйтесь, посмотрите как это работает на разных входных данных при вводе getline() и cin >> в разные типы.